# How to convert a date in C# from one format to another?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert "Jan 24, 2002" to "01/24/2002". I'm running into one wall after another. Can anyone shed some light one what I'm getting wrong with this?

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

DateTime oDate = Convert.ToDateTime("Jan 24, 2002");

DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(oDate , "MM/dd/yyyy", provider);

String myString = result.ToString("MMddyyyy");

return myString;
```

Thank you.

Comment: You only need to parse it once. Why are you doing it twice?

Comment: I was under the impression that I had to convert it from a string to a datetime, then change the format, and then convert it back to a string. I guess I'm mistaken?

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have a format.  Format only exists in a string.  So parse it into a `DateTime`, then format that however you need.

Comment: MSDN seems to have plenty of samples listed: [DateTime.ToString() Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are:

1. Converting to `DateTime`
2. Converting the `DateTime` from the previous step to another `DateTime`, not sure why.
3. Converting the resulting `DateTime` to a `string` in a format you don't want.

All of that could just be:

```
return DateTime.Parse("Jan 24, 2002").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

And, as @Igor mentions, for the case where the code is run under a different culture, you should pass the `CultureInfo` that suits the format:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
return DateTime.Parse("Jan 24, 2002", culture).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

*Note*: `DateTime`s do not have format. The format is given to the string when you use `ToString()`

Comment: Thank you, Camilo. This worked perfectly. I have to wait another 5 minutes to approve your answer as the accepted one.